# Jquery Multiple Checkbox Filter of Content ANY/OR rather than ALL/AND

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, filter

I have gotten this jquery script to filter content by selecting multiple checkboxes:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="categorya" id="categorya" style="display: none;" />        
<j id="button" title="button">Check1</j></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="categoryc" id="categoryc" style="display: none;" />        
<j id="button" title="button">Check1</j></label>

<div class="categoryc categoryg categorye categoryf categoryh" style="display:none;">
<p style="width: 670px;">
Check1
</p>
</div>

<script>
$('j#button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
});
</script>
<script>
$('input').click(function() {
    var selector = $('input:checkbox').map(function(){ 
        return this.checked ? '.' + this.id : ''; 
    }).get().join('');
    console.log(selector);  

    var all = $('div[class^="category"]');
    if(selector.length)
      all.hide().filter(selector).show()
    else all.hide();
});
</script>
```

This is the final page 
    http://www.justlegalservices.it/jls/brick/filter

But I would like to show results as OR/ANY of the checked boxes, not AND/ALL. As it is now, the content won't display if categorya and categoryc are both checked. Only if categoryc is checked alone. I want the content to display even if categorya is checked as well.  If someone could point me in the right direction or to the pertinent documentation I'd be grateful.

Comment: Is it `$(''j#button'')` or `$('j#button')` ?

Comment: What do you mean by all/and & any/or?

Comment: sorry it's $('j#button').  Any/OR - even if one of the checkbox categories is selected the content is displayed. ALL/AND - only if both checkbox categories are selected the content is displayed.   As it is now the content won't display if categorya and categoryc are checked.  It will if only categoryc.  I want the opposite.